# How to get the right row in a sorted DataView?

Tags: .net, winforms, forms, datagrid

I have a DataGrid containing a small table. Until now, I had a double click handler on this grid which iterated over all rows to find the selected one:

```
DataTable table = (DataTable)this.dataGrid.DataSource;
int selectedRow = -1;
for (int i=0; i<table.Rows.Count; i++)
  if (this.dataGrid.IsSelected(i))
    selectedRow = i;
    break;
  }
if ( selectedRow != -1 ) {
  DataRow row = table.Rows[selectedRow];
  // More code ...
}
```

Problem: When the user clicks on a column header and sort the table, `table.Rows` does not return the right rows. It still contains the unsorted rows.

How can I get the right column?

Edit 1: I have a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid`, not a `DataGridView`. I don't know the difference, because I don't know .Net very much. Can I simply replace DataGrid with DataGridView?

Comment: You have to be careful with the terms "DataGrid" and "DataGridView". There is a "DataGrid" Windows.Forms control in all versions of .NET. In 2.0 the "DataGridView" Windows.Forms control was introduced. These two controls do not share the same properties.

Comment: "Can I simply replace DataGrid with DataGridView". If this new development then yes replace it.

Comment: "DataGrid Control Overview (Windows Forms)" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxfa9793.aspx

Comment: Note there is a Web "DataGrid".

Comment: Its not a web platform, and its an older application, and simply replacing it didn't working, because DataGridView seems to lose some other properties that gets set in the app code. But I'll look further, thanks.

Comment: @ZeissS: Got it. Use the code I added to my answer. It is the code I use for a production/commerical application from early 2005 where I also must use a `DataGrid`.

Comment: @ZeissS: Just a note. Both controls work well. I like the DataGridView because it is flexible and easy to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### DataGrid (Windows)

Try `DataGrid.GetSelectedDataRows` below, where `MyBase` is the name of your `DataGrid`.

```
    Public Function GetSelectedDataRows() As DataRow()
        Dim oSelectedRows As New ArrayList
        Dim oDataTable As DataTable = DirectCast(MyBase.DataSource, DataTable)
        For i As Integer = 0 To oDataTable.Rows.Count - 1
            If MyBase.IsSelected(i) Then
                oSelectedRows.Add(oDataTable.DefaultView(i).Row)
            End If
        Next
        Return DirectCast(oSelectedRows.ToArray(GetType(DataRow)), DataRow())
    End Function
```

#### DataGridView

Use the `SelectedRows` property. It returns the collection of `DataGridViewRow` objects. Since you know you are binding a `DataTable`, the `DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem` property will be a `DataRow`. Check the above object help topics for examples.

#### References

- *Differences Between the Windows Forms DataGridView and DataGrid Controls* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171628.aspx
- *DataGridView Class* at 
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx
- *DataGrid Class* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx

#### Excerpts

> The DataGrid control is retained for
>   backward compatibility and for special
>   needs. For nearly all purposes, you
>   should use the DataGridView control.
>   The only feature that is available in
>   the DataGrid control that is not
>   available in the DataGridView control
>   is the hierarchical display of
>   information from two related tables in
>   a single control. You must use two
>   DataGridView controls to display
>   information from two tables that are
>   in a master/detail relationship.

Comment: Yes, as I said. Could you specify what's wrong with my code sample? I don't see what shouldn't "seem right"...

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `DataGridView.SelectedRows` property? Then use `DataBoundItem` for those rows to access underlying data. This may be of type `DataRowView`. In that case, use the `DataRowView.Row` property.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvrow in dataGrid.SelectedRows)
{
  DataRow row = null;
  if (dgvrow.DataBoundItem is DataRowView)
    row = (dgvrow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row as DataRow;
  else
    row = dgvrow.DataBoundItem as DataRow;

  // ... stuff
}
```

Comment: Since the question was changed to `DataGrid` control, your code is not relative, so it makes no difference if I feel there is something odd about the code. :O)

Comment: I didn't realize he was talking about DataGrid now :-D

Comment: Yeah, he got me also. :O) Thank goodness I still support a .NET 1.1 application, so had the code ready.